# Is it possible to turn off all sounds on iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, audio

I haven't got iPod touch to test it. Also I can't find the answer with simulator.

My app sends Local Notifications with sound to user. On iPhone you can disable all sounds using Ring/Silent switch. But what about iPod touch? Is it possible for user to disable all sounds including Local Notifications? I know that you can turn off notification sound for specific app in **Setting › Notifications**. I'm asking about turning off all sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not silence switch on the iPod Touch, so the user can only step down the volume until the device is muted.

Comment: For example, user muted iPod by volume buttons. What will happen if he will receive Local Notification? There will be no sound? What will happen if he try to play song in default Music app?

Comment: well, it´s kind of tricky. there are two sound levels: music and sound effects; user can decide whether the volume buttons affect sound effects or not; if not, then the volume buttons only change music volume, so alerts will not be affected. hope this helps.

Comment: So, is there a way to mute iPod completely? Both music and sounds effects? How user decide whether the volume buttons affect sound effects or not? I guess there is a switch in Settings->Sounds.

Comment: Yes, the setting is ins Settings->Sounds (sorry for not mentioning before). Basically, if the switch is set: buttons will control effect + when you open a music app, then buttons control music volume, or you can double tap the home button and control the volume by swiping a slider. I the switch is not set, then buttons control music volume + you go to settings->sounds to tone down/up alerts.

Comment: Sergio, thanks for your answers. Last one question. :) On iPhone you can't completely disable alerts sound in Settings->Sounds. When you swipe slider to the left (to the minimum), alerts are still working, but very quietly. What about iPod? Can you test it. Just swipe slider to the minimum and tell me can you hear something or not at the minimum. (there will be test melody during swiping)

Comment: absolutely nothing to be heard. btw, this was on a iOS5 device.

Comment: So, it's possible to mute ringer on iPod using volume buttons. On iPhone only Ring/Silent switch will mute it completely. Thank you, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Settings .... Sounds ..... Ringer and alerts and turn it down to the max and it works :)

Comment: To the max? You mean minimum?